# How to change the color on my navigation bar?

Tags: html, css

I currently have a website where I have tried to make the navigation bar links be white before they are clicked/visited and orange after they have been visited. I have made them orange but can't seem to make them white.

So far my `html` version is set up as

```
<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="index.html"> Home </a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

and my `CSS` is set up as

```
nav {font:white; background-color: #474644; }
```

What can I do to make the links white without being visited? I also have some other links in my paragraphs and footers which I don't want to be affected.

Comment: <nav>
 <ul>
 <li><a href="index.html"> Home </a> </li>                             </ul>                                                                                                     </nav>                                                                                               This is my html set up

Comment: Seems like your main issue is that the page refreshes.CSS in such case cannot achieve what you're asking for: "Make active after navigating" - JS can and a backend logic can.

Answer (score 0):

For links before they are visited:

```
nav a:link {
  color: white;
}
```

For links after they are visited:

```
nav a:visited {
  color: orange;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe you should just use the "color" property to define the color of the text. Also use a class to specify that only those links should be affected by those properties. Maybe:

`nav a{ color:white; background-color: #474644; }`